# Does AG-Grid has any event like onDataLoaded or is there any other ways to do the same thing?

Tags: javascript, events, ag-grid

I didn't find any event or similar event on the documentation that indicates `AG-Grid` will info us all the data are rendered on the page.

**Issue:**
We are using `jsPDF` to export page to PDF, but on IE, if the we have too many data, IE will render the table very slow. Now we are using document onRead event to trigger `jsPDF` to export page to PDF, but when document is ready, the AG-Grid only draw a table infrastructure, few data are rendered, most of the cell are blank.

Please help me out, thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean data is rendered? Or download from the AJAX call?

Comment: Hi Pavan, Yes, the data is completed rendered.

Comment: Did you try firstDataRendered? If it's the first time your data is loaded this might help. Also can you provide a fiddle for the same so that it's easier to know what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Hi Pavan, Yes, I tried, the event onFirstDataRendered doesn't work for me. We are using jsPDF to export page to PDF, but on IE, if the we have too many data, IE will render the table very slow. Now we are using document onRead event to trigger jsPDF to export page to PDF, but when document is ready, the AG-Grid only draw a table infrastructure, few data are rendered, most of the cell are empty.